# How to use variables set inside a beforeEach with hardhat testing

Tags: solidity, javascript, hardhat, mocha, chai

```js
describe("func", function () {
    let owner
    beforeEach(async function () {
      const [owner] = await ethers.getSigners()
    })
it.only("should correctly set the address", async function () {

      console.log(owner.address)
      
    })
  })
```

I get this error when I try to run the tests, and when I hover my mouse over 'owner' it says 'any' instead of SignerWithAddress.

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'address')

Comment: Do u need “const” there? It is by the way normal JavaScript testing :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have defined local constant called `owner`, but haven't assigned the global `owner` value. Just remove the `const` from `beforeEach` action and you should have access to globally defined `owner`:

```
    beforeEach(async function () {
      [owner] = await ethers.getSigners()
    })
```